# Can I trigger a script from a Google Form WITHOUT a Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, form-submit, google-forms

I don't really want to store my form responses in a spreadsheet, I just want to get an email sent to me with the results (and then maybe connect to a curl API to add it to my CRM)

I've got it working if I use as a spreadsheet, but can't do it just using code in the form?

When using

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
```

I just get e not defined.

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 2):

> We can add our script to Google form directly.

We don't need to necessarily save responses in some google sheet to run scripts.

Steps:

1. Go to Google Form
2. Go to Options (3 vertical dots)
3. Script editor
4. Add your script there

Answer (score 0):

Having them linked to a spreadsheet is an easy way to set it up and if you ever loose one it will always be there in the spreadsheet.  If you want get an email for every submision.  The you can use onFormSubmit trigger.

[form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

You can create the trigger with this:

```
function createOnFormSubmitTrigger(funcname) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onFormSubmit().create()
  }
}
```

This one helps to prevent you from creating more than one trigger for a given function..

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

This could be a simple way to make the email happen.

```
function emailme(e) {
  var keys =Object.keys(e.namedValues);
  var msg="";
  for(key in e.namedValues) {
    msg+=Utilities.formatString('\n%s: %s ',key,e.namedValues[key]);
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail('your email address', "Form submission", msg)
}
```

[Gmail Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)

Run this once to link up the emailme script with the onFormSubmit Trigger.

```
function makeTrigger() {
  createOnFormSubmitTrigger('emailme')
}
```